# How to automatically render an rmarkdown (.Rmd) file upon page load?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have two rmarkdown files.
Rmd #1:

````
---
title: "RMD1"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

<style type="text/css">

h1.title {

text-align: center;
color: DarkBlue;
font-size: 38px;

}
</style>


```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
                  choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

      sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                  min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
    ),
    plotOutput("eruptionsPlot")),

    server = function(input, output) {
      output$eruptionsPlot = renderPlot({
      hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
           xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
    },
    options = list(height = "600px")
)
```
````

Rmd #2:

```
---
title: "RMD2"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

<style type="text/css">

h1.title {

text-align: center;
color: DarkBlue;
font-size: 38px;

}
</style>
```

I have RMD1 and RMD2 tied to two action buttons in the shiny app code below. My question: **How do I have RMD1 render automatically (as if the action button got automatically clicked) when the page loads?**

Bonus question: When I first run the app, I need to click an action button twice to render the rmarkdown file. I got around that by adding in a line below that is not connected to any action button and outputs the rmarkdown file. No idea why that works or if there is a more logical/elegant solution.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

rmd_list <- list("rmd1.Rmd", "rmd2.Rmd")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::panel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, align="center",
             actionButton("rmd1", "RMD1"),
             actionButton("rmd2", "RMD2")
      )
    )),
  ,uiOutput("uioutput")

))

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

#So that I dont need to double click on an action button to render any rmarkdown. No idea why this happens, but this is my solution to the "double click" problem.
  output$uioutput <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(includeHTML(rmarkdown::render(rmd_list[[1]])))

  observeEvent(input$rmd1, {
    output$uioutput <- renderUI({
      withMathJax(includeHTML(rmarkdown::render(rmd_list[[1]])))
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$rmd2, {
    output$uioutput <- renderUI({
      withMathJax(includeHTML(rmarkdown::render(rmd_list[[2]])))
    })
  })  

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `reactiveVal` to store which `.Rmd` is selected and shown. By setting the initial value to 1, it will show your `rmd1.Rmd` file upon loading.

You only want one `output$uioutput` and would try to keep out of observers in general. In this case, the `output` will render whatever the `reactiveVal` is set to (1 or 2).

Your `observeEvent` buttons will just change your `reactiveVal` to either 1 or 2.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

rmd_list <- list("rmd1.Rmd", "rmd2.Rmd")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::panel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, align="center",
             actionButton("rmd1", "RMD1"),
             actionButton("rmd2", "RMD2")
      )
    )),
  uiOutput("uioutput")
))

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveVal(1)

  output$uioutput <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(includeHTML(rmarkdown::render(rmd_list[[rv()]])))
  })

  observeEvent(input$rmd1, { rv(1) })

  observeEvent(input$rmd2, { rv(2) })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This answer didn't seem to work unfortunately. The app loads, but nothing is visible until I press button rmd2. Rmd1 only starts working *after* I press rmd2.

Comment: Ben, turns out my packages were not fully updated! Your solution works! Thank you.